# Где допускаю ошибку в JS Element.classList.contains()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

День добрый.
Стоит задача - как только состоялось событие `.click` начинается проверка на наличие класса в элементе.
Вижу ошибку через инструмент разрабочика в браузере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите из-за чего она возникает ошибка в JS

```
$('#contacts-of-network aside > div > *:nth-child(2) > div:first-child').click(
  function() {
    // console.log($('#contacts-of-network aside > div > *:nth-child(2)').classList.contains('active'))
    if ($('#contacts-of-network aside > div > *:nth-child(2)').classList.contains('active') == false) {
      $('#contacts-of-network aside > div > *:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('#contacts-of-network aside > div > *:nth-child(2)').removeClass('active');

    };
    // .toggleClass('active');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы мешаете (и путаете) Javascript с jQuery.

В JQ не используется `.classList.contains()`, вместо этого есть метод [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

---

А ещё можно не искать каждый раз элемент, а взять его в переменную.

```
$('#contacts-of-network aside > div > *:nth-child(2) > div:first-child').click(function() {
  let el = $('#contacts-of-network aside > div > *:nth-child(2)');
  if (el.hasClass('active') == false) {
    el.addClass('active');
  } else {
    el.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Можно убрать `== false`, т.к. `hasClass` уже предполагает true или false... Можно тернарник забабахать.....

Comment: Можно, не не просто убрать, а заменить на `!el.hasClass('active')`, чтобы не менять тело условия.

Comment: Если `el` имеет `.active`, то `.hasClass()` вернёт `true`, правильно? И условие выполнить `el.addClass('active')`, но зачем добавлять класс, когда нужно его удалить? По этому и `!` в начале условия, чтобы инвертировать результат `.hasClass()`.

Comment: По вашей рекомендации придётся менять тело условия - `el.hasClass('active') ? el.removeClass() : el.addClass()`

Comment: Я о другом немного подумал)

Comment: Имхо поменять тело не проблема, чтобы читалось по-человечески))

Comment: Полностью согласен, но видать автору так проще, по этому и оставил без изменений. Условие то правильное.

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарий. 
Все мнения, на данной странице интересны.

Answer (score 1):

уберите == false, contains уже предполагает true или false, ==false в любом случае не должно, если не сработает то попробуйте услвоие задать с отрицанием через не

Comment: С условием всё правильно, но можно переписать и проще.

Comment: Оo я не знал что в jQuery .classList.contains() нет

Comment: Он есть, но нужно иначе использовать `$(element)[0].classList.contains()`, но проще `$(element).hasClass()`